# MariaDB tmpdir & table copy operations

Tags: mariadb, innodb, temporary-tables

I have a Linux server & MariaDB v10.0.33, where tmpdir is tmpfs (ram), for fast temporary table access; tmpfs is obviously limited in size.

MariaDB seems to use the same tmpdir location for alter table operations (table copy), that require a table copy;  these can require large amounts of space if tables are many Gb.

Old MySQL versions configure 'table copy' and 'temp table' separately;
Table copy written to tablespace & temporary tables written to tmpdir.

I am aware I can set 'innodb_tmpdir' per command.
Can MariaDB configured so that table copy & temporary tables use different locations?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bad idea to rob space in RAM for things other than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Furthermore, your example is flawed.  An `ALTER` that needs to copy works this way:

1. Create tmp table and populate it;
2. "Move" the table into where the original table is.

Step 2 is the issue:

- If the tmp and the original are in the *same* filesystem, these are fast operations involving the directory.
- If they are in *different* filesystems (and tmpfs is definitely different), the "move" is really a more-costly "copy".